# Spring task scheduler Multiple Instances on multiple machines detection

Tags: spring

I have made an Spring Task Scheduler services for sending e-mails at particular condition. This service is running on multiple machines.

If one machine service sends the e-mail then I have to stop the other service for sending the email.

How can I detect this without using persistent storage flag that one machine service has executed its e-mail code?

Answer (score 2):

You have basically 3 options:

- Use a shared data store of some form (e.g. data base) that all nodes connect to. That's what we do usually.
- Make the nodes "talk to each other" so a particular node could the check the state of its peers before sending email. For this you could use [JGroups](http://www.jgroups.org/).
- Have your email service run on only one of the nodes.